# windows form will run in background automatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I develop a windows form like this

```
Source Folder:         Destination Folder:
    Start Button
```

I also set a timer after every 2 minutes program will run. And also I move a shortcut of the application in the start up folder. now what I want is after first time I press the start button program form will close but will run in background and also every time I log on the PC
.exe will run in background automatically. I mean what I want after 1st time I press the start button form will never come to UI, it will always run in background. Please help me how I able to do that.
If you don't understand my query please let me know.

Comment: Not exactly clear what are you trying to do. Please show some code and what you have so far.

Comment: search for Windows Services.

Comment: You cannot use a Windows service if you want to display some sort of user interface. As others have said, this question does not make any sense whatsoever. You will need to rephrase your question. Please also consider showing an actual screenshot rather than a poor-quality ASCII illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to work upon your communication. Question is phrased very badly.
There are 2 option, either by Process or by command line in windows start

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(realCMD.ToString(),realARGS.ToString());
                    if (domainName != null)
                        psi.Domain = domainName;
                    psi.UserName = realUsername;
                    psi.Password = securePassword;
                    psi.CreateNoWindow = true; 
                    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
```

If we do this, a window will ALWAYS be shown uppon execution.

The command to launch programs from the command-line in Windows is "start"

Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

```
START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/AFFINITY <hex affinity>] [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program]
      [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in  window title bar.
    path        Starting directory
    B           Start application without creating a new window. The
                application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
                enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
                the application
    I           The new environment will be the original environment passed
                to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.
    MIN         Start window minimized
    MAX         Start window maximized
    SEPARATE    Start 16-bit Windows program in separate memory space
    SHARED      Start 16-bit Windows program in shared memory space
    LOW         Start application in the IDLE priority class
    NORMAL      Start application in the NORMAL priority class
    HIGH        Start application in the HIGH priority class
    REALTIME    Start application in the REALTIME priority class
    ABOVENORMAL Start application in the ABOVENORMAL priority class
    BELOWNORMAL Start application in the BELOWNORMAL priority class
    AFFINITY    The new application will have the specified processor
                affinity mask, expressed as a hexadecimal number.
    WAIT        Start application and wait for it to terminate
```

You may want to use the MIN option to start a program minimized

Answer (score 0):

Hide() the window before it has been loaded at startup of application. Look up regedit start with windows c# on google for examples on how to start your app with windows, and use the Timer class to show your app every x minutes and use Show() to show it.

To make it appear as if there is no window at all while it's hidden, disable taskbar icon, disable notification tray icon, and set Show in Taskbar to false.

OR

Maybe a better way, would be to create a Task in Windows Task Scheduler when the program first launches that says "open my app every x minutes.". When your app opens, do your work, and when the work is done, or when user exits, exit the app and the app will open again at next scheduled time.